# How to set pivot to center/middle of custom control. [Visual studio]

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Environment : Visual studio C#/VB

Sometime I need to set a position of my custom control.
I must refer to ctrl.left
 then minus ctrl.width/2

Example VB code.

```
             dim centerCtrl as integer = ctrl.left - (ctrl.width/2)
```

Ok.it's not problem. But if i need to use it often. It's not comfortable. alright?

So what should I do? 
Have a method or class for set center?
if i refer to position of ctrl. it should mean center only.

Comment: You can write a method to set center

Comment: you mean create constructor.if i create new instant. it will call method for set like this................................

                 center = ctrl.left - (ctrl.width/2).

if need to use. I just call ctrl.center instead ctrl.left
Alright?

Comment: you can create class with overriden methods for each control that you want to display the text centered, and reuse it when you need it.